# If next section has class then add class to current section

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a class to the current section if the next section class has the class "card_wrapper"

This is what I have but I can't seem to get it to function correctly.

HTML example:

```
<div class="main_content">
   <section id="cont1"></section>
   <section id="cont2"></section>
   <section id="cont3" class="card_wrapper"></section> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $('.main_content section').each(function(){
    if($(this).next('section').hasClass('card_wrapper')) {
      //add class to con2 section
      console.log('found section');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Provide  the html to ?

Comment: if($(this).next('section').hasClass('card_wrapper')) {

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to function correctly" - what happens?

Comment: `closest` looks back up the dom. At a  guess, you want `next`. Showing us your HTML would help.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly nothing happens. But at least I don't get any errors.

Comment: The closest() method returns the first ancestor of the selected element. An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on. You should be using Next().

Comment: Your code should work fine provided the sections exist within an element that has the class main_content, you've included jQuery, and load the script properly. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1ktyvrwm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were simply missing a call to `addClass` as demonstrated below.

```js
$('.main_content section').each(function(){
    if($(this).next('section').hasClass('card_wrapper')) {
      $(this).addClass("added")
    }
  });
```

```css
.added{ background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_content">
<section id="cont1">1</section>
<section id="cont2">2</section>
<section id="cont3" class="card_wrapper">3</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class to the current section using [**addClass**](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main_content section').each(function() {
    var $currentSection = $(this);
    if ($currentSection.next('section').hasClass('card_wrapper')) {
      $currentSection.addClass('newclass');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_content">
  <section id="cont1">cont1</section>
  <section id="cont2">cont2</section>
  <section id="cont3" class="card_wrapper">cont3</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.main_content section').each(function(){
   if($(this).next('section').hasClass('card_wrapper')) { 
        console.log('found section with id ' + $(this).attr('id') );
   }
});
```

I've created a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/5rgvfqbm/1/